# PowerShell remove all comments from a script

Tags: regex, powershell, comments

I'm looking for a way to strip all comments from a file. There are various ways to do comments, but I'm only interested in the simple `#` form comments. Reason is that I only use `<# #>` for in-function `.SYNOPSIS` which is functional code as opposed to just a comment, so I want to keep those.

*EDIT: I have updated this question using the helpful answers below.*

So there are only a couple of scenarios that I need:

a) whole line comments with `#` at start of line (or possibly with white-space before. i.e. regex of `^\s*#` seems to work.

b) with some code at the start of a line, then a comment at the end of the line.
I want to avoid stripping lines that have e.g. `Write-Host "#####"` but I think this is covered in the code that I have.

I was able to remove end-of-line comments with a split as I couldn't work out how to do it with regex, does anyone know a way to achieve that with regex?

The split was not ideal as a `<#` on a line would be removed by the `-split` but I've fixed that by splitting on `" #"`. This is not perfect but might be good enough - maybe a more reliable way with regex might exist?

When I do the below against my 7,000 line long script, it works(!) and strips a huge amount of comments, BUT, the output file is almost doubled in size(!?) from 400kb to about 700kb. Does anyone understand why that happens and how to prevent that (is it something to do with BOM's or Unicode or things like that? Out-File seems to really balloon the file-size!)

```
$x = Get-Content ".\myscript.ps1"   # $x is an array, not a string
$out = ".\myscript.ps1"
$x = $x -split "[\r\n]+"               # Remove all consecutive line-breaks, in any format '-split "\r?\n|\r"' would just do line by line
$x = $x | ? { $_ -notmatch "^\s*$" }   # Remove empty lines
$x = $x | ? { $_ -notmatch "^\s*#" }   # Remove all lines starting with # including with whitespace before
$x = $x | % { ($_ -split " #")[0] }    # Remove end of line comments
$x = ($x -replace $regex).Trim()       # Remove whitespace only at start and end of line
$x | Out-File $out
# $x | more
```

Comment: In Windows PowerShell, I believe `out-file` defaults to encoding UTF16-LE, probably with BOM.  You could try `Set-Content` instead, which defaults to ANSI encoding. For either command, you can use `-Encoding` parameter. The UTF8 encoding will have BOM with those commands.

Comment: This is great to know thanks, as soon as I used `Set-Content` the file size went down to 220k instead of 700k. I've never gotten my head around the use of these various encodings and why some are so bloated ... Thanks.

Comment: Where's your `$regex` defined?

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, the best approach to identify and process all comments is to use  PowerShell's language parser or one of the Ast classes. I apologize that I don't know which Ast contains comments; so this is an uglier way that will filter out block and line comments.

```
$code = Get-Content file.txt -Raw
$comments = [System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize($code,[ref]$null) |
    Where Type -eq 'Comment' | Select -Expand Content
$regex = ( $comments |% { [regex]::Escape($_) } ) -join '|'

# Output to remove all empty lines
$code -replace $regex -split '\r?\n' -notmatch '^\s*$'

# Output that Removes only Beginning and Ending Blank Lines
($code -replace $regex).Trim()
```

Comment: This is *amazing*. As often with your answers, it's a level way above things that I knew existed. Ast classes are some kind of 'dark art magic' to me. I see that your method here would definitely be the very best approach for a comprehensive solution. I think my need currently is a bit simpler though, so I've updated my main question (and used your removal of empty lines and line trim beginning/end, that is very useful thanks), if you have some solutions on the revised points in there that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do the inverse of your example:  Only emit lines that do NOT match:

```
## Output to console
Get-Content .\file.ps1 | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '#' }

## Output to file
Get-Content .\file.ps1 | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '#' } | Out-file .\newfile.ps1 -Append
```

Comment: Ideal, I've updated my question using your answer here as a basis, it's led me to a few other refinements that maybe you have an idea on how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [**@AdminOfThings**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) helpful answer using the [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast) parser approach but avoiding any regular expressions:

```
$Code = $Code.ToString() # Prepare any ScriptBlock for the substring method
$Tokens = [System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize($Code, [ref]$null)
-Join $Tokens.Where{ $_.Type -ne 'Comment' }.ForEach{ $Code.Substring($_.Start, $_.Length) }
```

Comment: It would be great if you could also provide an example + output using your code snippet. Especially since using this *AST* magic is much harder to read/interpret than a typical RE. (E.g. What is a type `Comment` and what's included in that?)

Answer (score 1):

As for the ***incidental* problem of the size of the output file** being roughly double that of the input file:

- As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60999714/45375) points out, [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) in *Windows PowerShell* defaults to UTF-16LE ("Unicode") encoding, where characters are represented by (at least) *two* bytes, whereas ANSI encoding, as used by `Set-Content` in Windows PowerShell by default, encodes all (supported) characters in a *single* byte. Similarly, UTF-8-encoded files use only *one* byte for characters in the ASCII range (note that *PowerShell (Core) 7+* now consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8). Use the `-Encoding` parameter as needed.

---

**A *regex*-based solution to your problem is *never fully robust***, even if you try to limit the comment removal to single-line comments.

**For full robustness, you must indeed use [PowerShell's language parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser)**, as noted in the other answers.

However, **care must be taken when reconstructing the original source code with the comments removed**:

- [AdminOfThings's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60999714/45375) risks removing *too much*, given the subsequent global *regex*-based processing with `-replace`: while the scenario may be unlikely, if a comment is repeated *inside a string*, it would mistakenly be removed from there too.
- [iRon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72964279/45375) risks syntax errors by joining the tokens *without spaces*, so that `. .\foo.ps1` would turn into `..\foo.ps1`, for instance. Blindly putting a space between tokens is *not* an option, because the property-access syntax would break (e.g. `$host.Name` would turn into `$host . Name`, but whitespace between a value and the `.` operator isn't allowed)

The following solution avoids these problems, while trying to preserve the formatting of the original code as much as possible, but this has limitations, because intra-line whitespace isn't reported by the parser:

- This means that you can't tell whether whitespace between tokens on a given line is made up of tabs, spaces, or a mix of both. The solution below replaces any tab characters with 2 spaces before processing; adjust as needed.
- To somewhat compensate for the removal of comments occupying their own line(s), more than 2 consecutive blank or empty lines are folded into a single empty one. It is possible to remove blank/empty lines altogether, but that could hurt readability.

```bash
# Tokenize the file content.
# Note that tabs, if any, are replaced by 2 spaces first; adjust as needed.
$tokens = $null
$null = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput(    
  ((Get-Content -Raw .\myscript.ps1) -replace '\t', '  '), 
  [ref] $tokens,
  [ref] $null
)  

# Loop over all tokens while omitting comments, and rebuild the source code 
# without them, trying to preserve the original formatting as much as possible.
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new() 
$prevExtent = $null; $numConsecNewlines = 0
$tokens.
  Where({ $_.Kind -ne 'Comment' }).
  ForEach({ 
    $startColumn = if ($_.Extent.StartLineNumber -eq $prevExtent.StartLineNumber) { $prevExtent.EndColumnNumber }
                   else { 1 }
    if ($_.Kind -eq 'NewLine') {
      # Fold multiple blank or empty lines into a single empty one.
      if (++$numConsecNewlines -ge 3) { return }
    } else {
      $numConsecNewlines = 0
      $null = $sb.Append(' ' * ($_.Extent.StartColumnNumber - $startColumn))
    }
    $null = $sb.Append($_.Text)
    $prevExtent = $_.Extent
  })

# Output the result.
# Pipe to Set-Content as needed.
$sb.ToString()
```

Comment: This code is crazy to read/understand. I don't see how this could be better than using a RegEx, especially, when dealing with simple EOL comments like `blah bla code # my comment`. (People still keep on saying that RE is not robust enough, when the thing that is not robust, are peoples lack of using it properly and taking into account it's *greediness*.) Would have been great to see some more detailed comments for that code. And where are those type keywords, such as `Comment` defined and listed?

Comment: @not2qubit, the reason this is better than a regex is stated in the answer. Yes, if you're only dealing with simple scenarios, the solution in this answer may not be worth the effort. No, it isn't just improper use of regexes; they're not sophisticated enough to parse languages such as PowerShell. If you follow the language-parser link in the answer, you should be able to find your way toward the [`TokenKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.tokenkind) enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

My take on the problem, minimizing use of regex (on comment matching/replacement part at least):

```bash
# $code = ...get string contents of file or script block...
$commentTokens = [System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize($code, [ref]$null) |
    Where Type -eq 'Comment'

$newCode = $code

# any unique token that we will replace at the end (could generate guid if we want to)
$newComment = "<#~xRMx~#>"
# $newComment = "<#{0}#>" -f [Guid]::NewGuid()

$overlapSize = 0

# Normalize all comments to a known comment value `$newComment`
$commentTokens | foreach {
    # adjust starting position based on previous replacement overlap sizes
    $start = $_.Start + $overlapSize 

    $newCode = $newCode.Remove($start, $_.Length).Insert($start, $newComment)

    $overlapSize += ($newComment.Length - $_.Length) # calculate overlap sizes
}

$newCode = $newCode -replace $newComment, "" `
    # -split '\r?\n' -notmatch '^\s*$' ` # uncomment to remove blank lines
    -join "`n"

$newCode
```

From my testing handles various comment configurations (single-line, multi-line, partial-line). Check out [this replit project](https://replit.com/@gerneio/PS-Get-CleanScript#main.ps1). You can fork it and play around with it.

Example input & output:

```bash
$ScriptBlock = {
    ## 1234
    <# idk #># hello
    # test
    $test = 1234; # testing abc
    <# line1
    line2
    line3
    #>
    Write-Host "Hello World"
}

...

# Output:
<#
    
    
    
    $test = 1234; 
    
    Write-Host "Hello World"

#>

# Output (w/ removing blank lines):
<#
    $test = 1234; 
    Write-Host "Hello World"
#>
```