# Read value of variable in .ps1 and update the same variable in another .ps1

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find an efficient way to read the value of a string variable in a PowerShell .ps1 file and then update the same variable/value in another .ps1 file.  In my specific case, I would update a variable for the version # on script one and then I would want to run a script to update it on multiple other .ps1 files.   For example:

**1_script.ps1** - Script I want to read variable from

```
$global:scriptVersion = "v1.1"
```

**2_script.ps1** - script I would want to update variable on (Should update to v1.1)

```
$global:scriptVersion = "v1.0"
```

I would want to update 2_script.ps1 to set the variable to "v1.1" as read from 1_script.ps1.  My current method is using get-content with a regex to find a line starting with my variable, then doing a bunch of replaces to get the portion of the string I want. This does work, but it seems like there is probably a better way I am missing or didn't get working correctly in my tests.

**My Modified Regex Solution Based on Answer by @mklement0 :**
I slightly modified @mklement0 's solution because dot-sourcing the first script was causing it to run

```
$file1 = ".\1_script.ps1"
$file2 = ".\2_script.ps1"

$fileversion = (Get-Content $file1 | Where-Object {$_ -match '(?m)(?<=^\s*\$global:scriptVersion\s*=\s*")[^"]+'}).Split("=")[1].Trim().Replace('"','')
(Get-Content -Raw $file2) -replace '(?m)(?<=^\s*\$global:scriptVersion\s*=\s*")[^"]+',$fileversion | Set-Content $file2 -NoNewLine
```

Comment: You should use the [PowerShell abstract syntax tree (AST) class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Generally*, the most robust way to parse PowerShell code is to use the *language parser*. However, *reconstructing* source code, with modifications after parsing, may situationally be hampered by the parser not reporting the details of *intra-line whitespace* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72970073/45375) for an example and a discussion.<sup>[1]</sup>

Pragmatically speaking, using a [regex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based [`-replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) solution is probably good enough *in your simple case* (note that the value to update is assumed to be enclosed in `"..."` - but matching could be made more flexible to support `'...'` quoting too):

```bash
# Dot-source the first script in order to obtain the new value.
# Note: This invariably executes *all* top-level code in the script.
. .\1_script.ps1 

# Outputs to the display.
# Append 
#   | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 2_script.ps1
# to save back to the input file.
(Get-Content -Raw 2_script.ps1) -replace '(?m)(?<=^\s*\$global:scriptVersion\s*=\s*")[^"]+', $global:scriptVersion
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/bTa1N7/1).

---

<sup>[1] Syntactic elements are reported in terms of line and column position, and columns are character-based, meaning that spaces and tabs are treated the same, so that a difference of, say, 3 character positions can represent 3 spaces, 3 tabs, or any mix of it - the parser won't tell you. However, if your approach allows keeping the source code as a whole while only *removing and splicing in* certain elements, that won't be a problem, as shown in [iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74043318/45375).</sup>

Comment: The regex solution will work for me. However, I had to slightly modify your example to prevent the dot-sourcing from running the script.  I updated my question to include the modified code

Answer (score 3):

To compliment the helpful answer from [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0). In case your do go for the [PowerShell abstract syntax tree (AST) class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast), you might use the `Extent.StartOffset`/`Extent.EndOffset` properties to reconstruct your script:

```
Using NameSpace System.Management.Automation.Language

$global:scriptVersion = 'v1.1' # . .\Script1.ps1
$Script2 = { # = Get-Content -Raw .\Script2.ps1
[CmdletBinding()]param()
begin {
    $global:scriptVersion = "v1.0"
}
process {
    $_
}
end {}
}.ToString()

$Ast = [Parser]::ParseInput($Script2, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)
$Extent = $Ast.Find(
    {
        $args[0] -is [AssignmentStatementAst] -and
        $args[0].Left.VariablePath.UserPath -eq 'global:scriptVersion' -and
        $args[0].Operator -eq 'Equals'
    }, $true
).Right.Extent
-Join (
    $Script2.SubString(0, $Extent.StartOffset),
    $global:scriptVersion,
    $Script2.SubString($Extent.EndOffset)
) # |Set-Content .\Script2.ps1
```