# Is there any way to test functions in a PowerShell script without executing the script?

Tags: powershell, pester, pester-5

I would like to define **stand-alone** functions in my PowerShell script and be able to Pester test the functions without executing the rest of the script. Is there any way to do this without defining the functions in a separate file?

In the following pseudocode example, how do I test functionA or functionB without executing mainFunctionality?

**script.ps1:**

```
functionA
functionB
...
mainFunctionality
```

**script.Tests.ps1:**

```
BeforeAll {
  . $PSScriptRoot/script.ps1 # This will execute the mainFunctionality, which is what I want to avoid
}
Describe 'functionA' { 
   # ... tests
}
```

I believe in Python, you can do this by wrapping your "mainFunctionality" inside this condition, so I am looking for something similar in Powershell.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainFunctionality
```

Ref: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: By moving `mainFunctionality` into a separate file :)

Comment: Use [AST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast) (`[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($Path, [ref]$null, [ref]$errors)[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile("$PSScriptRoot/script.ps1", [ref]$null, [ref]$null)`) to browse for the functions in your script and invoke them.

Comment: You could add an optional switch parameter to your script to skip "mainFunctionality". When including the script for testing, call it with the switch parameter.

Comment: @zett42 I think this is the best solution so far.  However, I was hoping there would be some solution that wasn't exposed by the "interface" of the script.

Comment: @iRon can you provide an answer or link to an example?

Comment: Another way without changing the interface of the script would be to simply check a unique variable. Test code then defines the variable before dot-sourcing the script.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`$MyInvocation.PSCommandPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.pscommandpath?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#system-management-automation-invocationinfo-pscommandpath) to determine who invoked your script, it's the closest I can think of to Python's `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

This property will give you the absolute path of the caller, from there you can extract the script's name, i.e. with [`Path.GetFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=net-7.0) and after you can determine what you want to do, for example, **call `mainFunctionality` if the caller's name equals to `main.ps1` or call `mainFunctionality` if the caller's name is not equal to `script.Tests.ps1`**, etc. Short demo below.

- **`myScript.ps1`**

```bash
function A {
    "I'm function A"
}

function B {
    "I'm function B"
}

function mainFunctionality {
    "I'm function mainFunctionality"
}

A # Calls A
B # Calls B

# Call `mainFunctionality` only if my caller's name is `main.ps1`
if([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($MyInvocation.PSCommandPath) -eq 'main.ps1') {
    mainFunctionality
}
```

Then if calling `myScript.ps1` from `main.ps1` you would see:

```
I'm function A
I'm function B
I'm function mainFunctionality
```

And if calling `myScript.ps1` from anywhere else (console or other script with a different name) you would see:

```
I'm function A
I'm function B
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the PowerShell [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.ast) to just grab `functionA` and invoke it:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    function functionA {
        Write-Host 'Do something A'
    }
    
    function functionB {
        Write-Host 'Do something A'
    }
    
    function mainFunctionality {
        # Do something
        functionA
        # Do something
        functionB
        # Do something
    }
    
    mainFunctionality
}

Using NameSpace System.Management.Automation.Language
$Ast = [Parser]::ParseInput($ScriptBlock, [ref]$null, [ref]$null) # or: ParseFile
$FunctionA = $Ast.FindAll({
    $Args[0] -is [ScriptBlockAst] -and $Args[0].Parent.Name -eq 'functionA'
}, $True)
Invoke-Expression $FunctionA.EndBlock

Do something A
```

Comment: Nice, but what about the dependencies of the function, e. g. a script variable or another function within the same script?

Comment: @zett42, good point, it was just meant as an AST example. It is probably better to seach for the `mainFunctionality` caller and remove that from the scriptblock, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74043318/1701026

Comment: I clarified my question to state that I am talking about stand-alone functions, i.e. have no external dependencies... But I would hope that the solution would also apply to a function that calls other functions in the same script, as long as none of them depend on external state (i.e. externally scoped variables).  However, I haven't looked yet, but maybe it is possible to mock script/global variables to account for these scenarios.