# How can I only allow a function to be run via a script and not the terminal wt.exe (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, shell, terminal, scope, windows-terminal

I have been trying to make a function for hours to only run if it's run by the script and not the terminal.

I have a Profile.ps1 in `C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\PowerShell\Profile.ps1` that is run on every terminal instance. Like a linux .bashrc file.

In my `Profile.ps1` file I have this.

```
# Get PowerShell Profile Path
$pwsh = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments") + "\powershell"

# Dot source the internal functions I only want to be able to access via script and not terminal.
. $pwsh\internal\funcs.ps1
```

And inside `$pwsh\internal\funcs.ps1` file I have this.

```
function MyPrivateFunction {
    Write-Host "Hello"
}
```

I have tried using `$MyInvocation.CommandOrigin` and it works as expected.

```
function MyPrivateFunction {
    if ($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq "Runspace") {
        return
    }
    Write-Host "Hello"
}
```

When I start a new terminal the string `"Hello"` is written to the screen.

And if I invoke the command MyPrivateFunction like this:
`PS C:\Users\Alexander> MyPrivateFunction`
It works and returns nothing.

But the problem I have is I don't want to write the if statement in all of the functions.

It would be a lot of code repetition, and wouldn't be good at all.

If I make a function like this in `funcs.ps1`:

```
function Get-Origin {
    if ($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq "Runspace") {
        Exit
    }
}

function MyPrivateFunction {
    Get-Origin
    Write-Host "Hello"
}
```

It doesn't work. Because when I call `MyPrivateFunction` it returns as `Internal` because it gets called by the `MyPrivateFunction` function.

So even if you type MyPrivateFunction directly in the terminal it would still be treated as `internal` and still print `"Hello"`.

And I only want it to run if it's ran by the script.

Kinda like pythons: `python if __name__ == __main__`.

I have also tried using .psm1 modules but it will still print `Hello`.

I have tried using a `.psm1 module` to import the function but it will still print `Hello` due to being in the same scope I would guess.

The only solution I have is writing the `if ($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq "Runspace")` on every function but I don't think that's a viable option due to a lot of code repetition.

There has to be something better than this.

I also think that this question is unique and has not been asked before. Because I have searched and tried the answer to use `PowerShell modules` but it doesn't function in the way I want it to be.

What I expect it to do is to only allow to run the `MyPrivateFunction` in the script and not via powershell terminal.

It's in there due to using dot sourcing the `funcs.ps1` file.

One way maybe could work is to run a python script and do everything in there but that would be another procedure.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75251803/15339544

Comment: If I use it on every function yes. But I cannot write it into a function because it will still print "Hello". So I would need to set the if statement on every function I write inside funcs.ps1 I cannot write the if statement into a function and use that function so I would need to put the if statement into every function inside funcs.ps1.

Comment: But I guess I could write the if statement in every function I can't find another possible way for now.

Comment: Have you tried using modules with `Export-ModuleMember -Function 'PublicFunction1','PublicFunction2', ...`? All functions that are _not_ listed there will be private functions and cannot be called outside of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally done it! Including using aliases.

```
C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\PowerShell
├── Profile.ps1
├── internal
│   ├── funcs.ps1
│   └── subfuncs.ps1
└── powershell.config.json
```

`Profile.ps1:`

```
$pwsh = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments") + "\powershell"

function Open-Function{
    if($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq "Runspace"){
        Write-Warning 'Cannot be run interactively'
        return
    }
    & $pwsh\internal\funcs.ps1 @args
}

function New-Ln-Link {
    Open-Function "New-SymbolicLink"  @args
}

function New-Admin-Right {
    Open-Function "Update-Rights"
}

function New-Wtd {
    param (
        [string[]]$Arguments
    )

    $targetPath = Join-Path (Get-Location) ($Arguments -join " ")

    # Assuming Open-Function is a custom command to call functions dynamically
    Open-Function "Start-WindowsTerminalInDirectory" $targetPath
}

New-Alias -Name ln -Value New-Ln-Link @args
New-Alias -Name admin -Value New-Admin-Right
New-Alias -Name wtd -Value New-Wtd
```

`subfuncs.ps1:`

```
function Update-Rights {
    if(!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
        $workingDirectory = Get-Location
        Write-Host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.UnboundArguments
        Start-Process -FilePath wt.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "-d `"$($workingDirectory)`" `"$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.UnboundArguments)`""

        Exit
    }
}
function Start-WindowsTerminalInDirectory {
    param (
        [string]$Directory = (Get-Location)
    )
    
    Start-Process -FilePath "wt.exe" -ArgumentList "-d $Directory"
}




function New-SymbolicLink {
    param(
        [string]$Source = (Get-Location).Path,
        [string]$Target
    )

    if (-not $Source) {
        Write-Error "Please provide a valid source path."
        return
    }

    if (-not $Target) {
        Write-Error "Please provide a valid target path."
        return
    }

    $Source = Join-Path (Get-Location).Path $Source

    New-Item -Path $Target -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value $Source
}
```

`funcs.ps1:`

```
Param(
    [parameter(Position=0)]$FunctionName,
    [parameter(Position=1,ValueFromRemainingArguments= $true)]$FunctionArgs
)
. $pwsh\internal\subfuncs.ps1
if($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq "Runspace"){Write-Warning 'Cannot be run interactively';return}
&$FunctionName @FunctionArgs
```

That's it!

You cannot invoke the `Start-WindowsTerminalInDirectory` directly in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing tab completion (which shouldn't matter since you shouldn't be running functions interactively), one possible solution is to have a script that calls your function script, executing the desired function, but only if it is run via script.

funcs.ps1:

```
Param(
    [parameter(Position=0)]$FunctionName,
    [parameter(Position=1,ValueFromRemainingArguments= $true)]$FunctionArgs
)
. $pwsh\internal\subfuncs.ps1
if($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq "Runspace"){Write-Warning 'Cannot be run interactively';return}
&$FunctionName @FunctionArgs
```

Then move all of your functions into subfuncs.ps1. Then you call that in your profile like:

```
$pwsh\internal\funcs.ps1 MyPrivateFunction
```

Or, if you don't like having to call the script by name you could make a function to call it, and gatekeep the caller function:

```
Function Call-Function{
    if($MyInvocation.CommandOrigin -eq "Runspace"){
        Write-Warning 'Cannot be run interactively'
        return
    }
    & $pwsh\internal\funcs.ps1 @args
}
```

Then in your script just `Call-Function myprivatefunction`, or if that's too long reduce the function name to `cf` or something, and it's just `cf myprivatefunction`.

Comment: How would one use an alias for this? like: Set-Alias -Name sayhello -Value Call-Function myprivatefunction?  A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'myprivatefunction'.